# Confirm Box not stopping controller action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Giving the user the option to see the rows returned from the search or not. If I hit Cancel, it still runs the controller code.

HTML:

```
   <td><input type="submit" name="SubmitSearch" id="search" value="Search" class="form-control alert-success" onclick="return rowcount()"  /></td>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function rowcount() {
    confirm("There are rows");
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OracleVerification(string company, string location, string product, string department)
    {

        List<OracleStringViewModel> oracleStringList = OracleStringRepository.GetOracleStrings(company, location, product, department);


        return View(oracleStringList.ToList());

    }
```

Comment: The construct `confirm()` returns `true` or `false`. You need to make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `confirm()` returns `true` or `false`. You need to make use of it. You forgot to use the `return` keyword:

```
function rowcount() {
    return confirm("There are rows");
}
```

The problem here is, the `confirm` actually `return`s the boolean value from the user, but it goes nowhere. You need to `return` it back to the calling place, which is the `input`'s `onclick` event.

Comment: It still will run code in the controller. Could it be MVC architecture that it will not regard the true or false from confirm window?

Comment: @rlo Then yes, you need to do something like an AJAX call to the controller, thereby you need to get the input from the user, and later, if the input was `true`, you should fire the AJAX call.

Comment: But this should really work. It will not allow the `click` event to happen at all. So this will not even access the controller, by not allowing the form to be submitted. Check and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I am sure that the false value from the confirm window would stop the execution and not post at all. So using Ajax should not be necessary since it would post to the controller.

Comment: @rlo Yes. That's what I mentioned in my previous comment. Didn't you see? Does this work?

Comment: It doesn't work with the advice given. As I searched for other questions regarding this issue, there isn't an answer on this specific issue that satisfied the question asked.  I may have to use JQuery dialog boxes. I will return with a solution

Comment: @rlo Can you make a snippet? Looks like something minorly wrong.

Comment: I tried this on another solution and it worked as we expected. There is an issue with the current solution that is preventing default functionality. Thanks for your time.